# Hebrew multilanguage [numbers]

Tags: css, multilingual, hebrew, bidirectional

I am not sure how to represent numbers in Hebrew. Current approach.

```
.links { 
  direction: rtl; 
  unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this,

```css
body {
  direction: rtl;
}
```

```html
<h3>
  <span style="color:#999; unicode-bidi: embed">15. This is mine</span>
</h3>
```

**EDIT:**

This is what you have done, i would say its incorrect.

```css
span {
  direction: rtl;
  unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
  color: #999;
}
```

```html
<div clas="links">
  <span>15. This is mine</span>
</div>
```

Gives **51**

When i use translator.

**Translated**

[image]

One sample method,

```css
.links span {
  direction: rtl;
  unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
  color: #999;
}

#num {
  unicode-bidi: embed
}
```

```html
<div class="links">
  <span id="num">15.</span>

  <span id="text">This is mine</span>

</div>
<div class="links">
  <span id="num">16.</span>

  <span id="text">This is mine</span>

</div>
```

Comment: Ok but you are saying that numbers dont need to be flipped.. for example 15. should stay .15 just with dot on another side?

Comment: if numbers are flipped they change to different value. 15 = 51

Comment: Ok so I need to flip text but keep numbers with unicode-bidi: embed ?

Comment: yes, as i mentioned earlier if original values are flipped new values would be given.

Comment: added more details:)

Answer (score 1):

You can use following css to get it 
You can read about `unicode-bidi` by following link

**[unicode-bidi](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/u/unicode-bidi/)**

```css
.box {
  direction: rtl;
  unicode-bidi: embed;
  color:tomato;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <p>12. Hello</p>
</div>
```